# C++ - Compare date with current system date

Tags: c

I have a date in tm format. how can I compare with the current system date. I just want to compare tm_year, tm_mon, tm_mday.

```
int second = atoi(dateinSecond.c_str());
tm * ptm;
ptm = gmtime ( second );
```

basically i have a collection of data which belongs to different date. So i want to filter data for the current date.

Thanks,
syd

Comment: Changed the label to "C" instead of "C++". They are two different languages, and this code is in C...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current time, use the `time` function:

```
time_t timeNow = time(NULL);
tm now;
tm* nowTemp = gmtime(&timeNow);
memcpy(&now, nowTemp, sizeof(now));

int second = atoi(dateinSecond.c_str());
tm * ptm;
ptm = gmtime ( second );

if (now.tm_year == ptm->tm_year &&
    now.tm_mon == ptm->tm_mon &&
    now.tm_mday == ptm->tm_mday)
{
    // Equal
}
```

The reason you must copy the `tm` structure is that `gmtime` return a pointer to an internal buffer, so if you call it again for your input date you will overwrite the previous time structure.

Comment: It is throwing below error.                                         Error 6 error C2664: 'gmtime' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'time_t' to 'const time_t *'

Comment: Thanks Eli,  It is still not giving me the currect info. I mean the year , month and date are correct, but the hours , min and sec are incurrect. My system date is 3 feb 2011 15.27. but according to the above code it is 3 feb 2011 9.55. what may be the problem?

Comment: I think I should use localtime().

Comment: This depends on your input that you want to compare to. However, a difference of whole hours should be expected from different time zones, not 5 hours and 32 minutes... What exactly are you doing?